# Unable to Access Environment Variables in Next.js API Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a project using Next.js 13 and API routes to interact with a database. I'm trying to store my database credentials in a .env file, but the variables are not being loaded.

I have verified that the .env file is being loaded, but when I log process.env, the output does not include the variables I have defined.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? How can I access the environment variables in my Next.js API routes? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've attempted to access the variables in the API route index.js using the following code:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(process.env.DB_NAME);
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
  console.log(process.env);
  res.status(200).send("OK");
}
```

Additionally, I have tried using serverRuntimeConfig in next.config.js as shown below:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
    return config;
  },
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And in my API route index.js:

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(serverRuntimeConfig.DB_HOST);
  res.status(200).send("OK");
}
```

However, the output is always undefined for the variables.

I also tried using getServerSideProps in a page route, but i got the same answer.

I have verified that the .env file is in the root directory of my project. I have also restarted the development server after making changes.

The expected output would'd be 'localhost'

my .env.local file:

```
DB_NAME: name
DB_USER: postgres
DB_PASSWORD: *****
DB_HOST: localhost
BD_DIALECT: postgres
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your .env file (take out your secrets and use asterisks instead, of course)? I’d like to see how you’re defining variables.

Comment: Of course, the .env contents are in the description now, i've tried with .env.local, .env.development and just .env, and the result is the same. Also using NEXT_PUBLIC prefix.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, thanks! For kicks and giggles, can you try setting your environment variables like this? -> MY_VAR=“some_string_here”. So one example using your naming would be: DB_NAME=“name”

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Check out this page: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env. See if that works!

Comment: It works that way, but the private keys are now visible to the browser, no?.

Comment: Possibly. Based on the instructions from the link below, it seems that only variables with prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` will be visible to the browser: https://refine.dev/blog/next-js-environment-variables/

Comment: Using env in next.config makes the variables accessible to the browser. I have confirmed this behavior. However, an alternative approach is to utilize serverRuntimeConfig and set the variables there. By doing so, you won't rely on the env files, which is considered the recommended practice, right?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables aren't defined correctly in your `.env.local` file.

Make sure the variables are defined with an `=` sign, without a space on either side of it:

```
.env.local

DB_NAME=name
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=*****
DB_HOST=localhost
BD_DIALECT=postgres
```

Also note `.env.local` will only be used when running `npm run dev`, it will not be used for `npm run build` or `npm run start` unless the `NODE_ENV` variable is explicity set to `development`.

Because of that I reccommend changing your `.env.local` file to `.env` to remove the possibility of `NODE_ENV` from affecting the initialization of your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, it was because of this. Now i feel stupid but I'm happy it's fixed haha

Comment: Glad I could help, it’s all part of learning!